# how to throtle 5 requests per minute in a win form application

Tags: winforms, throttling

I am building a form application and press on a button which is looping in while loop till it founds some results. But this looping is requesting some server. I would like to throtle these requests to max 5 requests in 1 minute. So there needs to come some logic which is sleeping till the new minutes started.  Please can someone help me?

Here is my code:

```
        public int RPMCounter { get; set; }

        private async void SearchCheapestAuction()
        {
            bool foundItem = false;

            textBoxLogging.Clear();
            textBoxLogging.Text += System.Environment.NewLine + "start";

            // 1 stay loooping till you found this item for the buynowprice
            while (!foundItem)
            {
                // 2 check if this is request number 5 in one minute
                if (RPMCounter <= 5)
                {
                    // 3 increase counter
                    RPMCounter++;

                    // 4 set searchparameters
                    var searchParametersPlayers = new PlayerSearchParameters
                    {
                        MaxBid = (uint)Convert.ToInt16(textBoxMaxStartPrice.Text),
                        MinBid = (uint)Convert.ToInt16(textBoxMinStartPrice.Text),
                        MaxBuy = (uint)Convert.ToInt16(textBoxMaxBuyNow.Text),
                        MinBuy = (uint)Convert.ToInt16(textBoxMinBuyNow.Text)
                    };

                    // 5 run search query
                    var searchResponse = await client.SearchAsync(searchParametersPlayers);

                    // 8 check if the search found any results
                    if (searchResponse.AuctionInfo.Count > 0)
                    {

                        // 9 buy this player for the buy now price
                        var auctionResponse = await client.PlaceBidAsync(searchResponse.AuctionInfo.First(), searchResponse.AuctionInfo.First().BuyNowPrice);

                        // 10 stop searching/buying, I found my item for the right price
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // 11 I access the 5 rpm, sleep till the next minutes begin and go search again?
                    return;
                }
            }

            textBoxLogging.Text += System.Environment.NewLine + "finished";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't handle it this way.
The way you designed this will have the following effect: You will make the server request 5 times in a row in arbitrarily short intervals, then you will wait for a minute and call again 5 times in a row in arbitrarily short intervals.
If that's what you intend to do, can you explain exactly why you need it that way ?
Limiting the number of calls to 5 per minute could be done easily by simply having a `System.Timers.Timer` with an interval of 12 seconds and checking if your request is done.
If it is and you haven't found the item, you can make a new one, and if it isn't, you can wait for the next time that your timer is elapsed.

It could look something like this:

```
private Timer _requestTimer;
private readonly object _requestLock = new object();
private bool _requestSuccessful;

private void StartRequestTimer()
{
    _requestTimer = new Timer(12 * 1000) { AutoReset = true };
    _requestTimer.Elapsed += requestTimer_Elapsed;
    _requestTimer.Start();
}

void requestTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    lock (_requestLock)
    {
        if (_requestSuccessful)
        {
            _requestTimer.Stop();
        }
        else
        {
            TryNewRequest();
        }
    }
}

private void TryNewRequest()
{
    lock (_requestLock)
    {
        //try a new asynchronous request here and set _requestSuccessful to true if successful
    }
}
```

In your main function, you would first call `TryNewRequest()` then you would call `StartRequestTimer()`. Note that the request has to be asynchronous for this to work properly.

Comment: Hi Matt, Thank you very much for your answer. Yes this is my target to implement: Limiting the number of calls to 5 per minute. Do you have some example in code for me please with the timer with intervals of 12 seconds?